# Pause/Suspend Process object

Tags: java, android

I have a line like this:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

And at some point I want to pause the process. For 3 seconds. Thread.wait() or Object lock; lock.wait() does not help since, the process is going in the background, not pausing.

I know it's not safe and dumb do to this, I just need to pause the execution of longer-output command.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you check Handler for that kind of operations on threads.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html